# Node script "Cannot find module"

Tags: node.js

I have the following file structure:

```
/avro.js
/node_modules/...
/package.json
/package-lock.json
```

I have run:

```
npm install javro yargs
```

In my `avro.js` I do:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
const { javro, SchemaRegistryAvroFetcher } = require('javro');
const yargs = require("yargs");

const options = yargs
  .scriptName("javro")
  .positional('inpath', {
    type: 'string',
    describe: 'path to JSON Schema file to convert'
  })
  .positional('outpath', {
    type: 'string',
    describe: 'path to save converted Avro Schema'
  })
  .help()
  .argv;
```

When I try to run the script I get:

```
./avro.js --help
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'javro'
Require stack:
- /Users/anentropic/Documents/Dev/Personal/myproj/avro.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/anentropic/Documents/Dev/Personal/myproj/avro.js:2:46)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/Users/anentropic/Documents/Dev/Personal/myproj/avro.js' ]
}
```

Node.js isn't my first language, but I thought this should work?

Comment: Looking at `node_modules/javro/package.json`, I don't see a `main` attribute. According to the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#main) it looks like that's necessary to `require` a package. It does have a `bin`, and the [javro npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/javro) page only shows an example of it being used as a CLI tool...so that might be the only usage of it?

Comment: Oh thanks!  I thought I was using this https://github.com/ExpediaGroup/javro where the README shows no cli (...both packages show `npm install javro`)

Comment: You might try this instead: `npm install https://github.com/ExpediaGroup/javro`. The `javro` you find if you search npmjs.org has a different repo, but you can install a package straight from github by using the url.

Comment: @David784 thank's again for your help! I will probably delete this question as it does not illuminate anything useful about programming with node.js, my problem was entirely that Expedia failed at releasing their library