# Module not found after being just installed

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, avro

Sorry I am not fluent with `node.js`. Below is what is happening to me, which I interpret as package not found although it was just installed.

It is probably wrong, so what happened and how to fix?

```
>:~/personal/schematosis# npm install --save-dev javro

up to date, audited 73 packages in 1s

13 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
>:~/personal/schematosis# node convert.js             
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'javro'
Require stack:
- <HOME>/personal/schematosis/convert.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<HOME>/personal/schematosis/convert.js:1:45)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'HOME/schematosis/convert.js' ]
}

Node.js v18.11.0
```

`convert.js` is copypasted from here https://github.com/ExpediaGroup/javro#use-javro-in-your-build

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with your code the issue is with the package you are using Expedia failed in releasing their library. You can find the same discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68414878/node-script-cannot-find-module)

You can look into another package that does the job.

P.S. Sorry I haven't worked on Javro so I cannot suggest you another package but you can look into this and see if this works [Javro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/javro)

Comment: The library you pointed to doesn't work witj json schemas, it converts avro to json examples.

Answer (score 0):

I see in the readme for that project that it says '--save-dev' while installing, but I feel like that's wrong. I would reinstall directly into 'dependencies' and omit the `--save-dev` flag.

Edit: Nvm new answer noticed that their latest release is broken. Disregard!

Comment: It's a build tool, so I think putting it into the `devDependencies` is just fine. Anyway, it shouldn't make any difference.